# django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have an apps called FAQ I am using django-vanilla-views, this apps was working but I got an error like in title above but the body description of the error say:
**NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_question' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['faq/delete/(?P\d+)/$']**

[image]

Here is the codes:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class QuestionType(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug    = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s " % (self.title)


class Question(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug        = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    category    = models.OneToOneField('QuestionType', blank=False, related_name='question')
    tags        = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s. %s " % (self.title, self.category)


from .models import Question from vanilla import CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView, ListView from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

# Create your views here.

class QuestionList(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "faq/question_list.jade"


class CreateQuestion(CreateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "faq/question.jade"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('question_list')


class EditQuestion(UpdateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'faq/question_list.jade'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('question_list')


class DeleteQuestion(DeleteView):
    model = Question
    success_url = reverse_lazy('delete_question')


from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import QuestionList, CreateQuestion, EditQuestion, DeleteQuestion

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
   # URL pattern for the
   url(regex=r'^faq/$', view=QuestionList.as_view(), name='question_list'),
   url(regex=r'^faq/create/$', view=CreateQuestion.as_view(), name='create_question'),
   url(regex=r'^faq/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=EditQuestion.as_view(), name='edit_question'),
   url(regex=r'^faq/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=DeleteQuestion.as_view(), name='delete_question'),
)

from vanilla import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/home.jade"


class TermsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "templates/question_list.jade"
    pass
```

configuration/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'', include('apps.pages.urls')),
                       url(r'', include('apps.faq.urls')),
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.jade

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse
    ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-left
        {% url 'home' as home %}
        {% if request.path == home %}
        li.active
            a(href="{% url 'home' %}") {% blocktrans %}Home{% endblocktrans %}
        {% else %}
        li
            a(href="{% url 'home' %}") {% blocktrans %}Home{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endif %}

        {% url 'about' as about %}
        {% if request.path == about %}
        li.active
            a(href="{% url 'about' %}") {% blocktrans %}About us{% endblocktrans %}
        {% else %}
        li
            a(href="{% url 'about' %}") {% blocktrans %}About us{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endif %}

        {% url 'contact' as contact %}
        {% if request.path == contact %}
        li.active
            a(href="{% url 'contact' %}") {% blocktrans %}contact{% endblocktrans %}
        {% else %}
        li
            a(href="{% url 'contact' %}") {% blocktrans %}contact{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endif %}

        {% url 'faq' as faq %}
        {% if request.path == faq %}
        li.active
            a(href="{% url 'question_list' %}") {% blocktrans %}FAQ{% endblocktrans %}
        {% else %}
        li
            a(href="{% url 'question_list' %}") {% blocktrans %}FAQ{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endif %}


        {% if request.user.is_staff %}
        li
            a(href="{% url 'admin:index' %}") {% blocktrans %}Admin{% endblocktrans %}
        {% endif %}
```

The error is about regex which is not clear why was working and now an error display!!
Need some help
Thanks

Comment: The ProgrammingError just means that you forgot to perform syncdb

Comment: @isobolev You are amazing man :) however, would like to give you a big thanks for your all comment and respond I am very new with python and in this project were I am working bin told when I run ./run will automatically run syncdb at the same times therefore I haven't run syncdb. I don't know much about stackoverflow if is there point I can give it to you please let me know I can do it now, with my pleasure

Comment: @isobolev the application is working but not create new faq: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError
ProgrammingError: relation "taggit_taggeditem" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_id", "taggit_taggeditem"."content_type_id" FROM "taggit_ta...   I run the syncdb again to make sure now something with taggit.

Comment: @isobolev run ./migrate all up to date and working :)

Comment: Great! @DilMac If you used my initial answer (about "get_success_url") and it helped, you could mark it as accepted. If you used Rohan's suggestion please accept his answer.

Comment: @isobolev the def get_success_url.... not help much because if I have or not it works, as you told me I have restarted again from zero two times the only error I received was run syncdb after I run everything was working :) there is only one issue left which is the edit_question not update all work only this one not working. Rohan had right what he wrote but I answer him that I input wrong code at the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify 'pk' parameter for 'delete_question' url. Something like this should work:

```
class DeleteQuestion(DeleteView):
    model = Question

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('delete_question', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

But yes, why do you want DeleteView to redirect to itself after deletion?

Comment: The idea of faq is much similar like the form here create question and update or delete the questions if not good as an example. I have add the function now the error change to: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_question' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['faq/delete/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Comment: @DilMac It does't look like error changed. Did you also remove success_url attribute from class? Also please show complete stack trace.

Comment: @isobolev many thanks for your respond, actually I put the error by mistake had 2 pages open have updated the details above. I added the function you recommended me but not much change that is what look like the error: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_question' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['faq/delete/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Comment: @DilMac I don't understand... still exactly the same error? Once again: did you remove 'success_url' attribute from DeleteQuestion class? And please post full stack trace you get.

Comment: @isobolev, Yes I have already deleted [ success_url = reverse_lazy('delete_question') ] I got the same error. There are three apps pages which is the main apps contact and faq apps contact it works gut faq apps not working if you look above error it shows ['faq/delete/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$'] why after <pk> show double \\ .???

Comment: @DilMac hm, that's strange... However I think the main problem is that you are still not passing the pk parameter. Try paying attention on where does this error come from, which line code causes exception, what's wrong with that line. It's hard to tell anything without that information. That's why I've been asking you for a stack trace. Also please consider Rohan's point: maybe simply success_url = reverse_lazy('question_list') is what you really need.

Comment: @isobolev I do very appreciate your comment with Rohan it's very nice to discuss with someone has more experiences. Let me tell you one thing this app faq is exactly as it is in other project which is working fine no any error I just copy and past the code. If you want can send you screenshot what is look like there I have been searching and searching is just because is regex can't catch the error but I will not give up must find soon or later, however a very big thanks for all comment and your answer :)

Comment: @DilMac you could upload your screenshot somewhere and add link to your question.

Comment: @isobolev I have delete all the faq apps and starting from null again all similar code but start all from null. I will add the last error I got which is complete different to old error. I have added some codes about base.jade may help because I have feeling maybe the error is in the base.jade file with the image of update error

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have 2 url's named 'question_list' ('^faq/$' and ''^faq/delete/(?P\d+)/$''). Change the second one to 'delete_question' and you should be fine

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake the actual code urls is delete_question not question_list

Answer (score 2):

Your success url is

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('delete_question')
```

But your `delete_question` url requires `pk` as parameter, there no `delete_question` url without parameter, hence you are getting the error.

Logically your success url should be `question_list` rather than `delete_question`

Comment: Hi Rohan thanks I write above was my mistake in the real code it's success_url = reverse_lazy('delete_question') not ('question_list'). Here is the error look like:NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_question' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['faq/delete/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Comment: The original code is what is look like: url(regex=r'^faq/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=DeleteQuestion.as_view(), name='delete_question'),